# Helm - function "Release" not defined

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have received an error:

```
Error: parse error at (helm/templates/deployment.yaml:22): function "Release" not defined
```

The referenced line is:

```
value: "test.{{ Release.Namespace }}"
```

Why am I getting an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice you have forgotten the period (`.`) before the release.

The period references the current scope, which, without using a `{{ with }}` template, is the root scope.

`Release` is part of the root scope therefore you should access it like so:

```
value: "test.{{ .Release.Namespace }}"
```